# Need a same relative level nodes (siblings) DAG algorithm in Python

Tags: python-2.7, ontology, directed-acyclic-graphs

So I am currently working on a quick and dirty Python project that supports a data structure made out of a dictionary with keys being GOIDs from the open biological ontology format.  It hashses to another dictionary that contains lists of parent nodes or terms and children nodes or terms that helps me form lists with all children or all ancestors for a given node in the ontology ( working with GO .obo file, if that helps anyone ).

My problem is that I have been looking for an algorithm that will help me return all the same nodes on the same level as a given node id which has to be relative because there could be more than one path to a node ( it is a directed acyclic graph, but there can be multiple parents per node ).  I essentially need to look up the parents of a node, store the children of the parents all on a common list, and then repeat this process on every node added without repeating nodes or slowing down the computation significantly.

I'm think this can easily be done using a set to prevent duplicate entries, and just keeping track of which parents I have visited until all parents of siblings have been visited without being able to add a new parent, but my suspicions are this might be terribly inefficient.  If anyone has experience with this kind of algorithm, and insights would be highly appreciated!  Hope this is clear enough for a response.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, so this is what I have developed so far, but it seems to keep giving me wrong values for some strange reason.  Is there a minor error anyone can see where I accidentally not terminating correctly?

```
  # A helper function to find generations of a given node
  def getGenerationals(self,goid):
    quit = False
    visitedParents = set()
    generation = set()
    tempGen = set()
    generation.add(goid)
    while not quit:
      quit = True
      generation |= tempGen
      tempGen = set()
      print "TEMP GEN:",tempGen
      for g in generation:
        parents = set(self._terms[g]['p'])
        for p in parents:
          if p not in visitedParents:
            visitedParents.add(p)
            print "Parent:",p
            quit = False
            tempGen |= set(self._terms[p]['c'])
    raw_input("Break")
    return generation

  # Working function
  def getGeneration(self,goid):
    generation = list(self.getGenerationals(goid))
    generation.remove(goid)
    return list(generation)
```